# How do I get the first list objects value using a second list objects result in a django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have two object lists: `firstobjectlist` and `secondobjectlist`. With these two lists I want to get the values of the first object using the second object list result values.

For example:

```
{% for i in firstobjectlist %}
    {% for value in secondobjectlist %}
        <td align="left">{{i{{value.id}}}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

When I excute the above code I get the error:

> "Could not parse the remainder: '{{value.id' from 'i.{{value.id'"

Can anyone help show me how it should be done?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do here .

 {{i{{value.id}}}}

is wrong .

Also instead so sending two separate list in template .Why not you are using the zip in your view.

Also explain why you want to do this ,this question seems to be unclear for me
share|edit|delete|flag

Comment: with {{value.id}} i will get a value let say 1 this value i want use as {{i.1}} so that i can display result of {{i.1}} in my HTML page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, django template variables have to have a space between the `{{` and the contents.

You could use [the `with` tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with) (presuming that the value of `value.id` is a key or index in `firstobjectlist`):

```
{% for i in firstobjectlist %}
    {% for value in secondobjectlist %}
        {% with value.id as j %}
            <td align="left">{{ i.j }}</td>
        {% endwith %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi Timmy i am not able to get the values can please explain me in detailed, and i am thinking that {{ i.j }} is same as {{ i.value.id}}

Comment: I tryed this but i am not able to get please help me out